# How do I configure an SPF record to allow all hostnames (A records) under my domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, email-server, spf, mx-record

Assume I have a domain, `foo.com`, that I am configuring the SPF records for.

Assume that I have dozens of mail servers (all running on `*.foo.com`) that I will be sending emails from.

These mail servers will NOT be included in the MX entry of my domain; the MX records are different as we have separate incoming servers.

How do I go about configuring an SPF record to whitelist my email sending servers?

I have looked into the `ptr` flag but it seems to be not recommended because "it adds overhead and exposes the domain to unauthorized third-parties"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`a` mechanism](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax#a) with dedicated subdomain e.g.

```
example.com. IN TXT "v=spf1 a:mailers.example.com -all"
```

and then introduce all your mail servers in DNS, e.g.

```
mailers.example.com. IN A 198.51.100.23
mailers.example.com. IN A 198.51.100.50
mailers.example.com. IN A 203.0.113.40
```

This allows you to just add new DNS `A` record every time you add a new mail server, without a need to modify SPF every time i.e. add a new `ip4` mechanism.

Things gets much more easy if the mail servers are on the same subnets, i.e. you just add server capacity but don't get new IP addresses from different ISPs. Many mechanism has a subnet prefix in its syntax, but I'd recommend using [`ip4`](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax#ip4) (and `ip6`) for this, e.g.

```
example.com. IN TXT "v=spf1 ip4:198.51.100.0/24 -all"
```

Comment: Thank you, the `a:mailers.example.com` idea is wonderful

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
"v=spf1 mx:foo.com a:senders.foo.com -all"
```

Would permit your MX machines and every A record under **senders.foo.com** and no others.

See [OpenSPF record syntax for some more examples](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax#ip4)